# ChipGroup - setOnCheckedStateChangeListener - not triggerring

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-components-android, android-viewbinding

I'm trying to use ChipGroup in a project. I'm adding chip items manuelly. It's working perfectly fine. But when I'm trying to click it, setOnCheckedStateChangeListener is not triggerring. What am I doing wrong ? How can I solve this problem ?

`Mainactivity Layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            style="@style/choiceChip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:selectionRequired="true"
            app:singleLine="true"
            app:singleSelection="true">

        </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`MainActivity Class`

> Edited As A List

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
import com.yasinsenel.chipdeneme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val chipList : ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
        chipList.add("A")
        chipList.add("B")
        chipList.add("C")



        chipList.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
            val chip = Chip(this)
            chip.text = s
            chip.id = index
            binding.chipGroup.addView(chip)
        }


        binding.apply {
            chipGroup.setOnCheckedStateChangeListener { group, checkedIds ->
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

    }
}
``
Dependency
``
```

dependencies {

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
```

Comment: You're adding a single chip and you have `selectionRequired="true"` and `singleSelection="true"`, i.e. one chip has to be selected. So you can't deselect that chip, and its selection state can't change. I don't know if adding through code like that automatically sets it to checked (it should?) but try it with two and see if it works. (Bear in mind that listener will only fire in single-selection mode: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup#setOnCheckedStateChangeListener(com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup.OnCheckedStateChangeListener))

Comment: I added item programmatically. Still not triggering, I edited my questions. You can check the codes

Answer (score 0):

You Should set chip Checkable when adding to checkGroup.
use this line

```
chip.isCheckable = true
```